# Is there a way to convert an array of bytes into a UTF-8 string?

Tags: text-editing, text, utf-8

There are now some files which contain raw bytes which are valid UTF-8 characters, e.g. a line of the file could be `'@\u0915\u0941\u091b@ \u092c\u093f\u0902\u0926\u0941 \u0938\u095e\u0947\u0926 \u0939\u0948\u0902'`

I want to restore them to their original UTF-8 strings and save the files.

Is there a way to do it in Emacs?

Comment: Are those UTF-8 encoded characters, or unicode code points (looks like the latter)?

Comment: I don't think you're actually talking about arrays, but if you *were* then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987299/utf-8-bytes-to-string would be a near-duplicate. You seem to be talking about buffers with incorrect character encoding? Reading `C-h i g (emacs)Specify Coding` may help?

Comment: @phils I don't think so. I set the encoding of the buffer to UTF-8. The characters simply don't get displayed correctly. It's a really strange issue. I just want to work on the characters in R, but R displays them literally as raw bytes, alongside with other English characters. If I manually copy it into R Console surrounded with quotes, it works. I just don't know why. But anyways I want to get them displayed/interpreted as normal strings no matter what's the cause of the issue. Emacs is the tool I use daily so I was seeking for a solution with it.

Comment: @npostavs If I type them into R Console I get "@कुछ@ बिंदु सफ़ेद हैं". Guess they are complete characters then? This example should be Hindi.

Comment: Okay, I'm a bit confused what bytes the *file* contains, does it literally have ``\`` `u` `0` `9` `1` `5`, or is that just meta-syntax you're using to talk about the character "DEVANAGARI LETTER KA"? What do you get if you put the cursor on that letter and do `C-u C-x =`?

Comment: @npostavs It literally has the above mentioned content. For example putting the cursor on `0` and using `C-u C-x =` returns `Char: 0 (48, #o60, #x30) point=3208 of 5634 (57%) column=49`. It's something returned by Amazon Mechanical Turk so I guess something is awry with either the setup of our data collection or the way MTurk works. Anyways now I just need to convert those literal characters back to their original UTF-8 characters...

Comment: Ah, so if I understand correctly ``'\u0915'`` is R syntax for the string `"कु"`. Does the R command line have an option to echo its input? So you could do something along the lines of `C-u M-| r --eval - RET`? Otherwise you have to parse it in elisp. Which shouldn't be too hard since the syntax is close to [the elisp syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/General-Escape-Syntax.html), apart from using single quotes. You can probably reuse `read`.